# A hypothesis about complex sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a convergent complex sequence $b_n$ with limit $b$ and a recursively defined sequence

$$
a_{n+1}=a_nb_n+1\,,a_0=1
$$

I was lead to the hypothesis: if $a_n$ converges, then $|b|<1$ is necessary. It is easy to see that the hypothesis holds, if $b_n$ is a constant sequence. Then $a_n$ is a geometric series. Or if $b_n$ is a sequence of non negative real numbers it holds too. Further it is not so hard to see that $a_n$ is bounded if $|b|<1$ and that $a_n$ is unbounded if $|b| > 1$ and $\Re(b)\geq\tfrac{1}{2}$. The last statement was yield with a coarse estimation, so there is space for improvements. That's all at the moment what I know about it. I would appreciate any ideas to attack this hypothesis or a counterexample.

I can give more details about the things I found out if wanted.

Comment: Observation: the initial value $a_0=1$ here is crucial to your hypothesis (if it's true). For every $b\ne1$, there are sequences $a_n,b_n$ satisfying the recursion that both converge: for example, let $b_n=b$ be constant and let $a_n=1/(1-b)$ also be constant. So if one allows arbitrary initial values, then convergence is easy to arrange.

Comment: You are right Greg, but the initial value $a_0=1$ is cruicial. Otherwise the hypothesis is worthless - as you showed. I found it in my work about polylogarithms. So it has a background and stands not for itself.

Comment: Another interesting observation is, that if $|b| \geq 1$ and $a_n$ converges and you changed the first value $b_0$ to another value the resulting sequence $a'_n$ diverges! I think this is a hard indicator for the truth of the hypothesis.